# find all combinations of given numbers in a given array size

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I need to find all combinations from size `n` that consists of the numbers in numbers array. I tried to do it with the function I wrote below but it takes a lot of time and memory to do it like that.

Is there a way to do it more efficient?

```
void createCombinationArray(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int n, ArrayList<Integer> start) {
    if (start.size() >= n) {
        monthsComb.add(new ArrayList<>(start));
    } else {
        for (Integer x : numbers) {
            start.add(x);
            createCombinationArray(numbers, n, start);
            start.remove(start.lastIndexOf(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When there are `k` elements in `numbers` you will get `k^n` combinations. Even for relatively small numbers this is a lot. So don't be surprised if it takes long and uses much memory

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself whether you really need to generate all of these lists ahead of time. Maybe it would be acceptable to generate them on demand.

Keep in mind that each of these lists can be represented by a number with `numbers.length` bits, `n` or more of which are set. You could work with a data structure of this sort to reference a list external to it.

It would be quite straightforward to write a List implementation with this behavior.

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

public class SelectiveList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final BitSet bitSet;
    private final List<T> list;

    public SelectiveList(BitSet bitSet, List<T> list) {
        this.bitSet = bitSet;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(nthOnBit(index));
    }

    private int nthOnBit(int n) {
        int onBits = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = bitSet.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0 && onBits < n; i = bitSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
            onBits++;
        }
        if (onBits < n) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        return i;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it more efficently (both for time and memory) is to store the result as `int[][]` instead of `Collection<List<Integer>>` (which I assume to be the type of the `monthsComb` field). You can do this because you know that if you have k numbers the result will be `Binomial(n, k)` combinations of n numbers.

Another way (as @Phia-CM suggested) would be to implement a non-recoursive version of the algorithm.

I know they are both uneasy to implement, but that's the way for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
package combination;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Combination implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {

    public Combination(final List<Integer> numbers, final int n) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.n = n;
        this.current = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        this.radix = BigInteger.valueOf(numbers.size());
        this.size = this.radix.pow(n);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean hasNext() {
        return this.current.compareTo(size) < 0;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<Integer> next() {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList(this.n);
        BigInteger value = this.current;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            result.add(i, this.numbers.get(
                    value.mod(this.radix).intValueExact()));
            value = value.divide(this.radix);
        }
        this.current = this.current.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        return result;
    }

    private final List<Integer> numbers;
    private final int n;
    private BigInteger current; 
    private final BigInteger size;
    private final BigInteger radix;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Combination cb = new Combination(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 6), 3);
        while (cb.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cb.next());
        }
    }
}
```